How can I install wall panels over wallpaper and remove them without damage?
Recently I came across some panels to install on the walls of my living room.
Now in the store, on the packaging and on the website, it's mentioned you can use assembly kit to mount it on the wall, but our walls have wallpaper and assembly kit is quite strong. It's a rental home, so when I have to leave, I don't want to rip the wallpaper of the walls and redo the entire living room. Or spend a lot of time tediously scraping the walls hoping I won't damage the surface. Is there a way to carefully remove the panels after I have mounted it or is it better I just drill and screw the panels on the wall and use filler afterwards?

It's better to talk to your landlord before making any such modification as a renter. And generally such an extensive modification is not a good idea as a renter. Any way you attach paneling will damage the wallpaper and may upset your landlord.

I don't see any description of this "assembly kit" on that page. Please revise your question to include the relevant text.

The assembly kit is mentioned in this sentence in the last paragraph of the descriptive text: "...op de muur of het plafond worden gekit." The last word in that sentence refers to assembly kit and that it can be used to be installed on the ceiling or wall.

@Ecnerwal. The landlord made clear it's not a big deal if I drill, as long as I cover it up when I leave. But to be honest, if I don't have to drill, then that has my preference.

Make the panels freestanding by mounting them to sheet goods with attached feet?

Drilling holes in wallpaper is difficult to repair, though.
